# How to print ValidationError?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have errors in from:

```
errors = form.errors.as_data()
```

and in template:

```
{% if errors %}
    {% for field, error in errors.items %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ field }} - {{ error }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

but it shows me:

```
first_name - [ValidationError([u'This field is required.'])]
```

How to get only message?

Comment: remove `{{ field }}`

Answer (score 1):

The [`as_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data) method is useful if you want to access the `ValidationError` instances. If all you want to do is access the error messages, then use `form.errors` instead of `form.errors.as_data()`

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field, error in form.errors.items %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ field }} - {{ error }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```